# Installing Stacks in Hydro

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-hydro, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry if this is a total noob question, but I can't seem to find a straightforward answer anywhere.  I have ROS install on my mac, and I'm trying to get some new stacks.  What is the correct way to check out and build stacks using ROS Hydro? I have a ros_catkin_ws setup in my home directory as described in the hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source documentation.

For example, I want to grab the camera1394 stack so I did the following

```
cd ~/ros_catkin_ws/src
rosws set camera1394 --git https: //github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394.git
rosws update camera1394
cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
catkin_make camera1394
```

(There's an extra space in the git repo address b/c this site won't let me post links)

The final `catkin_make` command spits out the following error

> CMake Error at
> catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:88
> (message): This workspace contains
> non-catkin packages in it, and catkin
> cannot build a non-homogeneous
> workspace without isolation.

If I instead try to `rosmake camera1394` I get the following:

> [ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['camera1394']
> [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

Interestingly, if I just try to `roscd camera1394` I get the following error

> roscd: No such package/stack
> 'camera1394

even though `ls ~/ros_catkin_ws/camera1394` shows that the package is there.

My `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` variable is currently set to `/Users/rand/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share:/Users/rand/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/stacks` by the `~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash` script.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89986/installing-stacks-in-hydro/) by [rand](https://answers.ros.org/users/2393/rand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2013-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394.git` repository is a catkin package. There is no notion of stacks in catkin.

Additionally, you should not be using `rosws` with a catkin workspace. There are different tools to keep catkin and rosbuild workflows completely separated.

rosbuild => catkin

- rosmake => catkin_make
- rosws => wstool
- manifest.xml/stack.xml => package.xml

If you want to build `camera1394` on top of your hydro workspace, I would recommend doing it in another small workspace, like this:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/camera1394_ws
$ cd ~/camera1394_ws
$ source ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash
$ rosinstall_generator --wet --exclude RPP --deps camera1394 > camera1394.rosinstall
$ wstool init src camera1394.rosinstall
$ catkin_make
```

That will fetch and build `camera1394` and all the packages it depends on *except* packages that are already in your RPP (from ~/ros_caktin_ws). Then you can `source ~/camera1394_ws/devel/setup.bash` to use the result.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rand](https://answers.ros.org/users/2393/rand/) on 2013-10-11**:
The --exclude RPP argument gets me a "rosinstall_generator: error: too few arguments"

As a larger question, is installing each new package in its own separate workspace the recommended way to organize things? If not, how do I add new packages to an existing workspace?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-11**:
Sorry that should be different, basically `camera1394` was interpreted as something to exclude. I'll update the answer.